# Clone a private flutter project repository from Github to Xcode in MacOS

Tags: flutter, github, flutter-ios

I have a flutter application written in Android Studio in Windows and I am able to run and test it on an Android phone. The project has git as source control and all the changes are committed to a private repository on Github. How do I clone this private repository from Github to Xcode on Mac to test in on a physical iOS device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just open the terminal on your Mac, navigate to the folder where you'd like to put this project, then enter

```
git clone https://..... (your link that you copy from Github)
```

it will clone the repo into that folder. Usually it works fine (at least for me with my own private repos), if it asks for password, you can input it in the url like this:

```
git clone https://githubuser:githubpassword@github.com/githubuser/project.git
```

And then just open the iOS part of the project in Xcode. As a side note, Android Studio works just fine on Mac too, so you can do everything there :)

Comment: But don't I need to use Xcode if I want to test my app on iPhone. Can we do that directly from Android Studio as well?

Comment: Yes it is possible to run an app on an iPhone emulator (for example) from the comfort of Android Studio, but you still have to do it on Mac. You'd still need to have Xcode installed though and to run on real iPhone it takes a bit more steps, but all it doable, also there is plenty of tutorials on this.